# Render an image from local file path instead of from assets in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, dart

I am currently working on a Flutter app designed to display images in widgets loaded from a REST API server. I do not plan to use the `/assets`, because rendering from asset is during compilation. Instead, I implemented an API call method to call during or after the initialization and download the required images into an external folder, and then (re)render them in the widget.

I am currently trying something like `Images.file(File(path\to\local\file))`.

Here is a snippet of code when I try to load an image:

```
Expanded(
  flex: 1,
  child: Container(
    color: const Color(0xFFFEF3F6),
    child: Center(
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
          color: const Color(0xFFE8AFC5),
        ),
        height: 300,
        width: 300,
        child: Center(
          child: Image.file(
            File(
              'C:\\Users\\xuyan\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\test files\\Yuzu Orange Avatar.png'
            )
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

However, I have an error like this during `flutter run`:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY IMAGE RESOURCE SERVICE ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following PathNotFoundException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot retrieve length of file, path = 'C:\\Users\\xuyan\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\test files\\Yuzu Orange Avatar.png' (OS Error: No such file
or directory, errno = 2)
```

I have checked my spelling of the path, whether the image is in the folder and even access permissions from Flutter side. However, it still cannot read even find my image.

Is there any other reason for the exception, or any other ways to display images from external local path after rendering aside from using assets?

Comment: Could this be related to using double backslashes? Did you try to use single backslash in path?

Comment: are you building for windows? why don't you load the image directly from the API?

Comment: @ZahidTekbaş I tried single backslashes, double backslashes, and ```r'``` plus single slashes, still does not work.

Comment: @CsabaMihaly Are you talking about the REST API? I plan to do a local resource file cache system, which stores the images on the device locally. The API is called when Flutter cannot detect the required image in the cache. So, I should first load the file to the directory then render.

Answer (score 0):

Desktop, Documents, and other directories covered by OneDrive require Administrator access (Or a user account with access). It's best not to save there even during test phase as the issues you may or may not face can be different from other clients.

It's best to cache your images instead of manually downloading and then using them, for instance, you can use [cached_network_image](https://pub.dev/packages/cached_network_image).
The package caches the URL's given to it, it supports Windows even though it's not listed. Here's a minimal example from the package's own documentation:

```dart
import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';

CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: "http://via.placeholder.com/350x150",
        placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
        errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error),
     ),
```

This will render the image URL given to `imageUrl` property, while displaying `placeholder` when the image is loading and `errorWidget` when facing an error.

On the other hand, you can use [path_provider](https://pub.dev/packages/path_provider) to get the path to AppData or Downloads directory, best for storing your application's downloads and reuse them.

Comment: Can you specify what the ```context``` and ```url``` in placeholder is?

Comment: @YangXu Those are passed to you by the package, `url` passes `imageUrl` you already gave and `context` is a BuildContext object.